# Reference line number of string from text file

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, line-numbering

I want to reference a line from a non-TeX text file that contains a fixed string. I just want to be able to get its line number. I'll need to do this several times for the same file, so it'd be nice if any solution didn't have to read the file each time it's used.

I found another SE question that had to do with listings that almost sorta kinda does what I want. It uses an escape character and embeds links into the source file. I could almost use this, but there are two things I don't like about it. 1. It would require me to edit the text file and add an escape character and some TeX code. I'd really rather not do this. 2. It seems to include the listing in the final result (pdf, whatever), which I do not need or want.

Comment: `grep -n 'pattern' non-tex-file > file.tex` and then `\input{file}` in your main LaTeX project?

Comment: Hmm. Possibly. I'd prefer something that made use of TeX stuff exclusively if at all possible, as this will at least sometimes have to be built on Windows.

Comment: Windows does not have an equivalent for `grep`? If I really had to go that rout, I'd look into `l3file` and `l3regex`.

Comment: What kind of tokens are permissible in the input file?  Is it purely catcode 11 and 12 stuff or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will present 2 solutions: simple and more complicated.

If the file is composed purely of textual material, then this simpler approach should work.  I use `readarray` to import the file into a `\def` with `\\` line separators added.  Then I use a nested `\listofitems` parsing to find the line containing the defined `\matchstring`.  The result is a macro `\lineindex` containing the (comma separated) line number(s) of the matched string in the file.  A `-1` indicates a string match was not found.

The simple code is intended if the file and search terms are simple text, without special characters.  As such, this version will experience 4 cases that will break the file-read, since it is being read with default LaTeX catcodes.  Those 4 cases are:

1. `#`
2. `%` will act as a comment and blot the remainder of the input line.
3. `\...` that forms an undefined macro name.
4. unbalanced `{` or `}`.

Even with balanced braces, there are additional limitations: the search item will not be found within a braced group; if a braced group spans multiple lines of the input file, the line from the `{` to that with the `}` will be considered a single line of input (i.e., the group will be forced to be considered on a single line).

Thus, this first approach should only be used for simple text searches.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,listofitems,pgffor}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.txt}
There came from Nantucket a lemur,
who texted his doctor in beamer.
  a misplaced italic
  made his problem seem phallic
but in fact he had bruised just his femur.
\end{filecontents*}
% THE STRING OF INTEREST IS PLACED IN \matchstring
% WHICH IS THE ARGUMENT FOR \prep
\def\setmatchstring#1{\def\matchstring{#1}}
\def\searchformatch#1{%
  \readarraysepchar{\\}
  \expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\expandafter
    \\\expandafter/\matchstring}
  \readdef{#1}\mydatafile 
  \def\lineindex{}%
  \readlist\mydata{\mydatafile}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mydata[]{%
    \ifnum\listlen\mydata[\zcnt]>1\relax
      \if\relax\lineindex\relax
        \xdef\lineindex{\zcnt}\else
        \xdef\lineindex{\lineindex, \zcnt}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \if\relax\lineindex\relax\gdef\lineindex{-1}\fi
}
\begin{document}
\setmatchstring{misplaced italic}
\searchformatch{mydata.txt}

The line containing the ``\matchstring'' is \lineindex.
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the more complex solution, all four of the limitations have been overcome with catcode trickery.  The `\setmatchstring` macro in this revision, does not use braced input, but follows an approach similar to `\verb`, in which the user specifies the delimiter that is not part of the search string:  for example, with an `@` delimiter

```
\setmatchstring @f}f}#@
```

will set the search string as `f}f}#`.  Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{readarray,listofitems,pgffor}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.txt}
Account: Framistat{$#@}
Password: \gY^&$%\{x#
Encrypted Hash Code: ef}f}#$_+{
Expiration: \today
\end{filecontents*}

% THE STRING OF INTEREST IS PLACED IN \matchstring
\def\setmatchstring#1{%
  \begingroup
  \def~##1#1{\gdef\matchstring{##1}\endgroup
    \catcode`\\=0 
    \catcode`\{=1 
    \catcode`\}=2 
    \catcode`\%=14
    \catcode`\#=6
  }%
  \catcode`\#=12
  \catcode`\%=12
  \catcode`\\=12 
  \catcode`\{=12 
  \catcode`\}=12 
  ~%
}
\def\searchformatch#1{%
  \readarraysepchar{\SFLINEEND}%
  \expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\expandafter
    \SFLINEEND\expandafter/\matchstring}%
  \def\tmpA{%
    \catcode`\#=12
    \catcode`\%=12 
    \catcode`\\=12 
    \catcode`\{=12 
    \catcode`\}=12 }%
  \def\tmpB{%
    \readdef{#1}\mydatafile
    \catcode`\\=0 
    \catcode`\}=2 
    \catcode`\{=1 
    \catcode`\%=14
    \catcode`\#=6 }%
  \expandafter
    \tmpA\tmpB
  \def\lineindex{}%
  \readlist\mydata{\mydatafile}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mydata[]{%
    \ifnum\listlen\mydata[\zcnt]>1\relax
      \if\relax\lineindex\relax
        \xdef\lineindex{\zcnt}\else
        \xdef\lineindex{\lineindex, \zcnt}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \if\relax\lineindex\relax\gdef\lineindex{-1}\fi
}
\begin{document}
\setmatchstring @f}f}#@
\searchformatch{mydata.txt}
The line index containing ``\matchstring'' is \lineindex.

\setmatchstring !%\{x#!
\searchformatch{mydata.txt}
The line index containing ``\matchstring'' is \lineindex.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose this is the best that can be hoped for. The limitations are unfortunate. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @LucasPaul Please see my revision that addresses all 4 of the limitations.

Comment: Ah, way cool. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasPaul It took me a long time (if you look at the revision trail), but I'm very happy with the result.